# The linker attempts to include all not used functions and template instantiations even with function level linkage

Tags: c++, linker

I have a library which uses templates very much to avoid rewriting the same code many times . But as known this leads to horrible compile times and in visual studio also leads to heavy and slow intellisense which makes coding on a computer with 4 GB of ram very noisy .

However most classes are designed so that they only can be instantiated with particular types and templates are there to avoid rewriting for each type , this made me move most of the implementations to `.cpp` files and use explicit template instantiation there .

For example I have :

```
// socket.h
template<class Protocol>
class socket
{

};

// socket.cpp
template class socket<tcp>;
template class socket<udp>;
template class socket<local::tcp>;
template class socket<local::udp>;

// sslstream.h
template<class NextLayer, class Engine>
class sslstream
{

};

// sslstream.cpp
template class sslstream<tcp::socket, openssl::engine>;
template class sslstream<tcp::socket, wolfssl::engine>;
template class sslstream<udp::socket, openssl::engine>;
template class sslstream<udp::socket, wolfssl::engine>;
// and so on


// websocket.h
template<class NextLayer>
class wsstream
{

};

// websocket.cpp
template class wsstream<tcp::socket>;
template class wsstream<sslstream<tcp::socket, openssl::engine>>;
// and so on for all possible layers
```

Problems begin when I try to use something like `wsstream<tcp::socket>` in any source that links to the library . The linker attempts to include all non-static functions and all template instantiations along the path and will emit errors for unresolved functions from openssl and wolfssl libraries if I don't pass them to the linker . This increases the program size and includes tons of unused code from openssl and wolfssl even if I don't use any ssl functionality at all ! And tens of template instantiations will be included and never referenced only because they are instantiated in the same translation unit !

I read that the linker in ordinary circumstances can't remove unused functions from an object file (either no to include it or include the whole object) because functions lie in the same code segmentation and the linker can't separate them easily .

Then I read about function level linking which is introduced to solve such problems (I think) and puts each function in a separated section so the linker can throw unused sections away

This is what I did :

- Enabled Function-Level Linking in the library project /Gy
- Enable Link Time Code Generation /LTCG in the program project and also /Gy

The lib file resulted was so huge : more than 60 MB ! Before it was about 8 MB .

I expected now the linker will be able no to include the unused code but the result exe didn't reduce in size and also had much code and strings from openssl and wolfssl !

Is this the expected result ? Or I'm doing something wrong ? and if this is intended , is there any method to separate the implementation from the template interfaces and not to be forced to include the whole instantiations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes to this question and looks for a solution to similar problem, this is what I ended with :

Instead of moving the implementation to a translation unit `.cpp` and instantiating all templates there I put the implementation in an internal header file and removed the templates instantiations from the header . For each template instantiation I made a `.cpp` file which includes the implementation header plus the underlying type interface and instantiate an instant of the class with this type .

Now each instantiation resides in its own file and the linker won't pull unused instants.

A drawback of this approach is the increased implementation files which are there only to go around this problem.